# Node app runs locally but crashes on heroku (process.env.PORT set)

Tags: git, node.js, heroku

I have this version of blog on my repo:
https://github.com/pandrei/pandrei_test/tree/master/pandrei-blog

(feel free to clone and test it)

as a result of this tutorial :

http://blog.davydewaele.be/node-powered-git-blog-with-wheat

I tested it locally and it runs ok, however it crashes on Heroku.

Heroku log :

```
2013-10-24T20:23:55.610646+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path=/ host=pandrei-blog.herokuapp.com fwd="---.---.---.---" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=25ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-10-24T20:23:55.590168+00:00 app[web.1]: path.exists is now called `fs.exists`.
2013-10-24T20:23:55.601900+00:00 app[web.1]:       ^
2013-10-24T20:23:55.601882+00:00 app[web.1]:       callback(err);
2013-10-24T20:23:55.605427+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/wheat/node_modules/git-fs/lib/git-fs.js:208:7)
2013-10-24T20:23:55.601326+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-10-24T20:23:55.605444+00:00 app[web.1]:     at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
2013-10-24T20:23:55.605439+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
2013-10-24T20:23:55.605456+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
2013-10-24T20:23:55.605464+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)
2013-10-24T20:23:55.605452+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:948:11)
2013-10-24T20:23:55.605415+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: undefined is not a function
2013-10-24T20:23:55.601639+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/wheat/node_modules/git-fs/lib/git-fs.js:208
2013-10-24T20:23:56.652015+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2013-10-24T20:23:56.669381+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

I  have just started using Heroku and I don't really understand why it crashes.

Could someone either explain the cause of this or how to "debug" this?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So two things jump out to me here:

1. It seems like you are running a different version of node locally than heroku is running.
2. `path.exists` is obviously the cause of the issue, this is a deprecated function.

I would [upgrade to the latest node version](http://nodejs.org) and see if you can reproduce locally (if so the first diagnosis was correct), then search your code for `path.exists` and replace it with [`fs.exists`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback), which should fix the issue : )

**EDIT**: After looking through and pulling down the source of wheat, I would honestly recommend trying a different blogging engine. Wheat is out of date, not maintained and is broken in all the latest builds of node. In addition, some of wheat's dependencies are written by the same author and are also unmaintained and broken in recent node builds. If you are planning on building a blog, you want to build it on technology that is well-maintained and actively updated, not something that is old and broken.

I would recommend checking out [ghost](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost) if you are after a smoother and more modern blogging system. It's very well-maintained, themeable, easy to deploy, and even has a gui for editing and creating posts in the back end. If you are looking for something a little more minimal and hacker-y, I'd recommend [jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) if you can get down with ruby, or [roots](http://roots.cx/) if you prefer node. I am the maintainer of roots, and it is actively maintained and updated, supports simple blogs made with just markdown files, and has a single command deploy to heroku. If you'd like for me to set you up an example blog, I'd be happy to add to this answer, just let me know : )

Comment: True, but I ran  find . | xargs grep 'path.exists' -sl in my repo root folder and there is no such function in my codebase

Comment: @pAndrei it's in a dependency of wheat

Comment: Might actually be an issue with wheat - it shows you the line that produced the error: `/app/node_modules/wheat/node_modules/git-fs/lib/git-fs.js:208` - is your version of wheat the latest in your package.json file?

Comment: Can you add the contents of your `package.json` file to the question?

Comment: The content is also in the repo

Comment: Ok now that I've got the repo I'll make this work and send you a pull request. I'll edit this answer, update it, and mention you in a comment when this is done @pAndrei

Comment: Ok @pAndrei - I pulled down your repo, tinkered with it and with wheat, and decided in the end that it's probably not worth sticking with wheat, for reasons I detailed in the edits to my answer.

Comment: Your answer is helpful and complete ! Thank you, @JeffEscalante